@JsonView returns empty for springframework above 3.2.5
Above some controllers I have specified:
@JsonView(Views.Public::class)

Where projection-based interface methods have @JsonView:
@JsonView(Views.Public::class)
fun getUsername(): String

Using dependencies:
id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.5"
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.17.2

works fine and returns correct results, however, any newer springframework version (up to the latest 3.3.2) returns empty string for any controller methods that use @JsonView.
